# React setState inside handleClick after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React component that changes state on button click *AND* after some timed interval, after button click, changes back to its original state.

Here is my simple code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const TimedButton = (props) => {
  const [user_id, setUserId] = useState("FIRST");


  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setUserId("SECOND");

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Trigger...");
      console.log(user_id)
      if (user_id) this.setUserId("FIRST");
    }, 1000); 
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        {user_id}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TimedButton;
```

On click, `FIRST` changes to `SECOND`, fine. After timeout (1 second), `user_id` is set back to `FIRST`, but for some reason it's not re-rendering the screen, that remains as `SECOND` (but at that point user_id is `FIRST`).

Comment: Typo?  Why are you prepending `this.` to `setUserId`?  (And how is that not producing an error on the console?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `this.` to call `setUserId`. I've created a sandbox with the updated code [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sleepy-darkness-3hpl56)